# How to ignore all child tables of dataset

Tags: c#, optimization, dataset, parent-child

I'm filling a dataset from a XML and later, making alterations in this dataset data.
Well, here is my (bad) code:

```
if (finalDS.Tables[x].TableName != "Signature" && 
    finalDS.Tables[x].TableName != "SignedInfo" &&
    finalDS.Tables[x].TableName != "CanonicalizationMethod" &&
    finalDS.Tables[x].TableName != "SignatureMethod" && 
    finalDS.Tables[x].TableName != "Reference" &&
    finalDS.Tables[x].TableName != "Transforms" && 
    finalDS.Tables[x].TableName != "Transform" &&
    finalDS.Tables[x].TableName != "DigestMethod" && 
    finalDS.Tables[x].TableName != "KeyInfo" &&
    finalDS.Tables[x].TableName != "X509Data")
                {
                   //do something
                }
```

Signature is top level node:
[image: Signature]

I don't want to alter anything inside "Signature".

Is there a better way to know if the table is "Signature" or any child of it?

Note: this code already works, I just want to make something less messy.